# How to rig two separate meshes (head and body) seamlessly to a single armature

Tags: mesh, armature, vertex-weights

I have two separate meshes, one for the body and one for the head. Both are tied to the same armature and posing works as expected (both meshes move according to the weighted vertex groups).

In order to get a seamless connection between the meshes (without actually merging the meshes, since i need to export them as separate skeletal meshes to Unreal Engine) i matched the most outer vertex loops on both meshes to be in the exact same place as shown in the screenshot. So theoretically the seams line up perfectly in rest pose.

[image: Matched vertex positions]

Obviously, when i start posing the armature the meshes slightly get offset relatively to each other, since the weights are not exactly the same on the most outer vertices.

[image: Misalignment after changing pose]

So my naive idea was to match the weight values for every two corresponding vertice pairs on the two meshes, like shown in the next screenshot.

[image: Weights on body mesh]

[image: Weights on head mesh]

However even after doing so the verts still diverge:

[image: Vertices offset even after matching weights]

So my question is: What did i miss? Shouldnt the two vertices have matching positions when posing, since they do have the same armature, same position and same weights?
Or is there any other well known method to achieve seamlessly moving separate meshes on one armature?

Thx all for your help!

P.S.: btw, hiding seams through clothing or anything like that is not an option here, since the character needs to be topless.

Comment: If you merge the objects then the verts (By Distance) then separate them again, it will probalby work. But the seams will be still visible if you use smooth shading.